# Prevent UserForm from Closing when another unrelated Worksheet in the same instance of Excel is closed

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a UserForm that connects to test equipment over GPIB or a serial port.  The UserForm vba code- behind sends a string to the test equipment and displays the result.  There is a While loop that does this about 3 times a second while the flag for the Connect button is true.  I open the form modeless so you can take notes or whatever with Excel.

This seems to work fine until I open another workbook that becomes part of the same instance as the UserForm. When the loop in the code-behind is running and I close a different workbook, the UserForm closes with the other workbook.

Can anyone explain why this happens and how I can prevent it so my UserForm stays open?

Update: I can see the same behavior using the example image attached[example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDM4C.jpg)

Comment: Can't replicate this behavior in a simple test (show a modeless userform, open another workbook, then close it).  The userform remains open.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.  I was able to replicate the behavior I am seeing by doing the same thing you did but adding a command button that starts a while loop (While True - DoEvents -Wend).  If you don't click the button to start the loop everything is fine.  If you start the while loop, open another worksheet, and then close the other worksheet, it takes the form down with it.

Comment: You need to post your example code.

Comment: How are you handling the loop in your actual form?

Comment: I didn't see a way to upload the file so I updated the original question with an image of what I described above to replicate the problem.

Comment: Is that what you're doing in the actual form you're having a problem with?

Comment: Instead of DoEvents, its querying over serial or a GPIB bus inside a while loop.  You also get the same weird behavior changing the while loop to a for loop.  It seems like the critical part is the code running behind the form.  I'm fairly confident fixing the problem in my simple example will fix the problem in my much more involved program.

Comment: My workaround was to convert it to a Winforms C# executable.  I'd still like to know why Excel acts strange with code running in the form.